# How to use the same class name over multiple modules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parent-child

How to use the same class name over multiple modules?

I've a main `ApplicationService`

```rb
# /app/services/application_service.rb

class ApplicationService; end
```

```rb
# /app/services/processing/queue/application_service.rb

module Processing
  module Queue
    class ApplicationService < ApplicationService; end
  end
end
```

```rb
# /app/services/processing/callback/application_service.rb

module Processing
  module Callback
    class ApplicationService < ApplicationService; end
  end
end
```

How to get rails to not be confused and to know to use `/app/services/application_service.rb`

All my services in `/app/services/processing/queue/` have `/app/services/processing/queue/application_service.rb`as parent class.

Comment: Use `::ApplicationService`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the FQN (fully-qualified name) `::ApplicationService` to refer to your top-level class.

```
module Processing
  module Callback
    class ApplicationService < ::ApplicationService; end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it seems it still gets confuse. For example: I've a method `foo` in  a class extending `Callback::ApplicationService` and sometimes it tells me this method does not exist. Sometimes it gets trough.

Comment: @DanielCosta JFYI, there's no class `Callback::ApplicationService` in your code. Only `Processing::Callback::ApplicationService`. When you have clashing names like this, be super-explicit about FQNs.

Comment: Yes, I meant `Processing::Callback::ApplicationService ` and not `Callback::ApplicationService`